# How to lazy-load or eager-load the sum of associated table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

We build some object in our controller:

```
  @sites = Site.find(:all, :conditions => conditions, :order => 'group_id ASC')
```

And then in the view (currently), we are doing something like:

```
@sites.each do |site|
   %p Site Name
     = site.name
   - actual = site.estimates.where('date<?', Date.today).sum(:actual_cost)
   %p
     = actual
end
```

Basically like that.

And of course this fires off a query for the Sites and then a query for N sites returned.  I know about eager-loading associations with @sites = Site.find(:all, :include => :estimates) but in this case it didn't matter because we're doing the SUM on the query which is special it seems.

How would I eager load the SUMs in such that I don't get all the crazy queries?  Currently it's over 600...

Answer (score 0):

*provide your conditions & ordering in this query only, which will push the result into a Hash.*

```
    sites = Site.includes(:estimates).where('estimates.date < ? ', Date.today)
.order('sites.id ASC')

actual = 0 
sites.map { |site|
  site.estimates.map { |estimate|  actual = actual + estimate.actual_cost }
}
```

From your explanation, I am assuming actual_cost is a column in estimate table.